# jquery how to remove an element and preserve the .next() reference

Tags: jquery, reference

I'm stucked with jquery selectors. 
I have the follow code

```
    var $tab=this.$tab_pages.find("li#abc");
    var $nextTab=$tab.next();               
    $tab.remove();
```

after the remove the variable $nextTab is become undefined and I can no more do stuff with it.
I tried to clone object or just hide the $tab and then remove it but without success.

Any help? Could someone explain me why the $nextTab is undefined?

Thanks

Gisella

Comment: Something else is causing the problem, as the above code should work fine.... http://jsfiddle.net/jJwgN/

Comment: Show us more code - I suspect this may actually be a scope issue.

Comment: i created my own test that show what i means   http://jsfiddle.net/mYAj7/14/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var $tab=this.$tab_pages.find("li#abc");
var $nextTab=$tab.next().clone();               
$tab.remove();
```

**EDITED CODE**

According to fiddle you have posted your code should be like this , check this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLxuq/)

```
var x = $("#tab-page li.tabactive").next();
$("#tab-page li.tabactive").remove();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: @bronzett Try the jsfiddle I linked above

Comment: no, still having problems.
I append my test code

    <div id="tab-page">
    <ul style="" class="tab-nav">
      <li id="a"><a><input value="a" /></a></li>
      <li id="b"  class="tabactive"><a><input value="b" /></a></li>
      <li id="c">  <a><input  value="c" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>​


and the js code


    var x = $("#tab-page li:tabactive").next();
    $("#tab-page li:active").remove();
    console.log(x);

Answer (score 0):

Your example had some errors in it.  Here's a fixed version...

http://jsfiddle.net/mYAj7/15/

```
var x = $("#tab-page li.tabactive").next();
$("#tab-page li.tabactive").remove();
console.log(x);​
```

You were trying to select `li:tabactive` - it should be `li.tabactive`

You were trying to remove `li.active`, not `li.tabactive`

You hadn't selected jQuery in the framework dropdown

Comment: i fixed the error. my code was executed twice and the second time the id didn't existed. thanks for your support